# Reset Password doesn't work with custom Policy

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

The change password doesn't work in Azure AD B2C with custom policy. Recently we have made a change in user creation. Now user doesn't login with username@domain.com but now the user can login with just the username as we have updated the signInNames while creating a user.

But, after making the change we have realised that the change password is not working.

What could be the reason  behind it and what is required to get it working?

It errors out with a message "Invalid username or password."

Thanks!

Comment: It errors out with a message "Invalid username or password."

Comment: Reset password will work if at all that user got created from Signup or Signin Policy/ Signup policy of B2C

Comment: We are creating user from Graph API(populating the signInNames).
before that email address was used for signIn

Comment: @Ramakrishna  Change password is not working since the user is now able to login with just the user name(without the domain.onmicrosoft.com). Not sure why it is not able to recogize user on the second page where it asks for old password along with new password.

Answer (score 1):

I tried on my side: if I enabled `forceChangePasswordNextLogin` when I created the user with the only username, upon using the username to login, I get the same error. But if I disabled `forceChangePasswordNextLogin`, I could succeed to log in by using the username.

Comment: If there is anything update, please let me know, thanks.

Comment: If the answer is useful for you, please help mark it, thanks!